# How to create an item for a scrolling list with scened2d

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I want to create an "item" template and add them to a `ScrollPane`

An item should contain an Image, a label and a button

Something like this:

[image]

I tried to do this with a table but I can't add a background to a row.

```
scrollTable.add(itemTest).fill().expandX();
scrollTable.row();
scrollTable.add(itemTest2).fill().expandX();
scrollTable.row();
etc..
```

What is the best way to create something like the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's about a class `ScrollPaneRow extend Table` as template?

```
public class ScrollPaneRow extends Table {
    Label label;
    TextButton textButton;
    Image image;
    public ScrollPaneRow(){
        //...
        setBackground(Drawable d);
    }
}
```

And then a VerticalGroup which contains the rows:

```
ScrollPaneRow row = new ScrollPaneRow();
VerticalGroup verticalGroup = new VerticalGroup();
verticalGroup.addActor(row);
```

And set the VerticalGroup as content of ScrollPane:

```
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(verticalGroup);
```

Comment: Thx for your answer it's a good solution, but nothing is showing up :/ even in debug mode